# Plot the plane so different condition has a different color

Tags: plotting

I have a list of functions defined on the plane, and I want to know which one of those functions is smaller than the other functions at particular points.

Currently, what I do is

```
Plot3D[{1 + 3/2 v, 1 + 2/3 m + 1/6 v, 9/4 + 1/8 v, 10/7 m, 
  m + Min[2/3, 1/2 m, v]}, {m, 1, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Red, Blue, Green, Black}, ViewPoint -> Bottom]
```

And I get a picture like this (it is a little bit rotated because I can't view 3D plots unless I'm moving it... but that's another question)

[image]

I feel there must be a smarter way than doing this without invoke plotting a 3D diagram.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Edit note: I added an alternative and then was encouraged to separate the two solutions.  If you upvoted because of the second solution, feel to retract it. (Sorry.)]

Here's a V10 solution with `ImplicitRegion`.

```
fns = {1 + 3/2 v, 1 + 2/3 m + 1/6 v, 9/4 + 1/8 v, 10/7 m, m + Min[2/3, 1/2 m, v]};

rgns = Table[
   ImplicitRegion[
    Reduce[{And @@ Thread[fns[[i]] < Drop[fns, {i}]], 1 < m < 2,  0 < v < 1}, {m, v}],
    {m, v}],
   {i, Length[fns]}];

Show[MapThread[
  RegionPlot, {rgns, Thread[PlotStyle -> {Orange, Red, Blue, Green, Black}]}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This also will plot the regions, but I can't figure out how to style the regions:

```
Show[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, MaxCellMeasure -> 2] & /@ rgns]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** There's got to be a better way than this:

```
meshToGraphics[rgn_] /; RegionDimension[rgn] == 2 :=
 With[{boxes = Cases[
    ToBoxes @ BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[rgn, MaxCellMeasure -> 2],
    _GraphicsComplexBox,
    Infinity]},
  ReleaseHold@MakeExpression[GraphicsBox@boxes, StandardForm]
  ];

Show[MapThread[
  meshToGraphics[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#1, MaxCellMeasure -> 2]] /. p_Polygon :> {#2, p} &,
  {rgns, {Orange, Red, Blue, Green, Black}}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice to see v10 functionality helping for a change. ;^)  +1

Comment: Nice update!  Really clean.  I think you should post that as a second answer; I'd surely vote again.

Answer (score 13):

Late, but I wanted to show a different way of visualizing the `ImplicitRegion` approach shown by MichaelE2 based on a workaround I came up with [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56238/probable-bug-in-highlightmesh-with-2d-convex-hulls-created-via-convexhullmesh):

```
fns = {1 + 3/2 v, 1 + 2/3 m + 1/6 v, 9/4 + 1/8 v, 10/7 m, m + Min[2/3, 1/2 m, v]};

rgns = Table[ImplicitRegion[Reduce[{And @@ Thread[fns[[i]] < Drop[fns, {i}]], 1 < m < 2, 
      0 < v < 1}, {m, v}], {m, v}], {i, Length[fns]}];

{r1, r2, r3, r4, r5} = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ rgns;
```

Then:

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[
    MeshCoordinates[#1], {Black, MeshCells[#1, 1], Opacity[0.6], #2, 
     MeshCells[#1, 2]}] & @@@ {{r1, Red}, {r2, Blue}, {r3, 
    Yellow}, {r4, Darker@Green}, {r5, Purple}}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion it's not a bad thing to use `Plot3D` for this as you offload plane intersection to the GPU.
You can get an orthogonal view like this:

```
Plot3D[
  {1 + 3/2 v, 1 + 2/3 m + 1/6 v, 9/4 + 1/8 v, 10/7 m, m + Min[2/3, 1/2 m, v]},
  {m, 1,2}, {v, 0, 1}
  , PlotStyle -> {Orange, Red, Blue, Green, Black}
  , ViewPoint -> {0, 0, -∞}
  , Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
  , Mesh -> False
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

```
flist = {1 + 3/2 v, 1 + 2/3 m + 1/6 v, 9/4 + 1/8 v, 10/7 m, m + Min[2/3, 1/2 m, v]}; 
pieceW = Piecewise[Table[{i, flist[[i]] == Min[flist]}, {i, 1, Length@flist}]];
```

**DensityPlot**

```
DensityPlot[pieceW, {m, 1, 2}, {v, 0, 1},  
 PlotPoints -> 200, ImageSize -> 500, 
 ColorFunction -> ({Orange, Red, Blue, Black, Green}[[#]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImagePadding -> 25]
```

[image]

**ContourPlot**

```
ContourPlot[pieceW, {m, 1, 2}, {v, 0, 1},
     PlotPoints -> 200, ImageSize -> 500, Contours -> Range[5], 
     ContourShading -> RotateRight[{Orange, Red, Blue, Black, Green}],
     ContourStyle -> {Orange, Red, Blue, Black, Green}]
```

[image]

**RegionPlot**

```
regions = And @@@ (Outer[Less, flist, flist] /. x_ < x_ :> Sequence[]);
RegionPlot[regions, {m, 1, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 500,  PlotPoints -> 100,
           PlotStyle -> {Orange, Red, Blue, Black, Green}, ImagePadding -> 25]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for providing alternatives, but it's worth noting that this takes much longer to render than the code in my answer because this cannot (or at least does not) offload the work to the GPU.

Answer (score 3):

*This is my second answer.  I was encouraged to post this separately.  There is some sense to that, as it lets the community sort out the best solution, instead of tying two solutions together.*

From [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58228/how-to-do-a-region-plot-with-many-functions/58238#58238) to [How to do a region plot with many functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58228/how-to-do-a-region-plot-with-many-functions)

When `m` and `v` have `Ordering[fns, 1]` returns the index of the function whose value is least.  By setting the contour levels between the indices, we can plot the regions indicating which function has the least value.

```
fns = {1 + 3/2 v, 1 + 2/3 m + 1/6 v, 9/4 + 1/8 v, 10/7 m, m + Min[2/3, 1/2 m, v]};

ContourPlot[Ordering[fns, 1], {m, 1, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 Contours -> 1/2 + Range[Length@fns - 1], 
 ContourShading -> {Orange, Red, Blue, Green, Black}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To plot the regions indicating which function has the greatest value, use `Ordering[fns, -1]`.