# Conversion of 3D plot to 2D Contour Plot

Tags: plotting, conversion

Is it possible for Mathematica to convert a 3D plot into a 2D contour plot without having to recompute the values for each point? I realize that looking directly down at the 3D plot will be similar to the contour plot, but I'm wondering if Mathematica is be able to take the 3D plot as input and give the 2D contour plot as output.

Comment: Tangentially related: [(55352)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55352)

Comment: Hi, I noticed that you haven't accepted either answer.  Is there some aspect of your problem that neither addresses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your 3D plot is in `Graphics3D` format, you should be able to just extract the points on the graph and use `ListContourPlot`.

```
f[x_, y_] := -E^(-(1 + x)^2 - y^2)/3 + 
  3*E^(-x^2 - (1 + y)^2)*(1 - x)^2 - 
  10*E^(-x^2 - y^2)*(x/5 - x^3 - y^5);
cp = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Computed from function"];
pic = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotPoints -> 100];
lcp = ListContourPlot[pic[[1, 1]], PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLabel -> "Computed from 3D plot"];
GraphicsRow[{lcp, cp}]
```

[image]

Comment: What does `pic[[1,1]]` do? What would be the difference between `pic[[1,1]]` and `pic[[1,2]]` (besides the fact that Mathematica doesn't like `pic[[1,2]]`)?

Comment: @user85503 `thing[[position]]` represents part extraction. If you execute `Short[InputForm[pic], 4]`, you'll see that, internally, `pic` has the form `Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts_,_],_]`. Now, `pic[[1]]` grabs the `GraphicsComplex` (since it's the first argument of `Graphics3D`) and `pic[[1,1]]` grabs the first argument of the first argument, namely the points - which is exactly what we need.

Answer (score 11):

While this is overkill, I'm just trying everything I can do with these new (in **V10**) and exciting `Mesh` and `Region` functions. So here we go:

```
f[x_, y_] := -E^(-(1 + x)^2 - y^2)/3 + 3*E^(-x^2 - (1 + y)^2)*(1 - x)^2 - 
              10*E^(-x^2 - y^2)*(x/5 - x^3 - y^5);

gr = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100];
```

We cleverly discretize the `Graphics` object:

```
dgr = DiscretizeGraphics[Normal[gr /. {(PlotRange -> _) :> 
      PlotRange -> All, (Lighting -> _) :> Lighting -> Automatic}]];
```

And finally:

```
ListContourPlot[MeshCoordinates[dgr], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]