# Transforming the axes of a Contour Plot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, coordinate-transformation, projection

I have contours of the following function
$$\Psi(\nu,\mu) = -\frac{1}{4} e^{-2 \mu} \cos{2 \nu} - \frac{1}{2} \mu$$
in terms of $(\nu,\mu)$:

[image: original contour plot]

I need to obtain the contours for $\Psi$ in terms of a different set of parameters $(x,y)$, which are defined using
$$x=\cosh{\mu}\cos{\nu}\\
y=\sinh{\mu}\sin{\nu}$$

Is there a straightforward way to transform the axes, through post-processing or otherwise?

For interpretability, a parametric 3D plot of ($\Psi,x,y$) through

```
ParametricPlot3D[{\[Psi], x, y}, {\[Nu], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Mu], -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None]
```

yields the following:

[image: 3D parametric plot]

I tried using the alternative solution from [this relevant problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55688/conversion-of-3d-plot-to-2d-contour-plot) to project this 3D plot down to a 2D contour plot, but my parametric plot doesn't seem to be a compatible `Graphics3D` object. Is this approach less straightforward?

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

ψ[ν_, μ_] := -1/4 E^(-2 μ) Cos[2 ν] - μ/2

ParametricPlot3D[
 {Cosh[μ] Cos[ν], 
  Sinh[μ] Sin[ν], ψ[ν, μ]},
 {ν, 0, π}, {μ, -2, 2},
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &},
 MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue},
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y, HoldForm[ψ[ν, μ]]})]
```

[image]

```
sol = (ψ[ν, μ] /. Solve[
       {x == Cosh[μ] Cos[ν], y == Sinh[μ] Sin[ν], 
        0 < ν < Pi, -2 < μ < 2}, {μ, ν}, Reals, 
       Method -> Reduce] /. C[1] -> 0) // Simplify;

Show[
 ContourPlot[#[[1]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
    ColorFunction -> #[[2]],
    PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
      LegendLabel -> #[[3]]],
    FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y}),
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    MaxRecursion -> 2,
    PlotLabel ->
     StringForm["``", HoldForm[ψ[ν, μ][x, y]]]] & /@
  Transpose[{sol, {"TemperatureMap", "MintColors"},
    {"Lower\nHalf", "Upper\nHalf"}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
x = Cosh[u] Cos[v];
y = Sinh[u] Sin[v];
```

and you see that {u,v} and {-u,-v} give the same {x,y} values. Further if v==0, +u and -u result in the same x/y values. The same with u==0. We therefore restrict u and v e.g. to the first quadrant.

With:

```
psi[v_, u_] = -1/4 Exp[-2 u] Cos[2 v] - 1/2 u;
```

We now first create a table with {[u,v],y[u,v],psi[u,v]}:

```
dat = Flatten[Table[{x, y, psi[u, v]}, {u, 0, 2, .1}, {v, 0, 3, .1}], 1];
```

With this data,  we create an interpolating function, As the data are not on an grid, we will get a warning that only linear interpolation is used, what does not harm our calculation.

```
intpol = Interpolation[dat];
```

Now we can create a countour plot with variables x and y

```
ContourPlot[intpol[u, v], {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 3}, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- We use `ParametricPlot` to draw the region `{x[μ, ν], y[μ, ν]}` where `{ν,  0, π}, {μ, -2, 2}` and then use `MeshFunction` to add the meshs which satisfies the condition `Φ[ν, μ]=meshs` where `meshs = {-3, -2, -1, -.9, -.8, -.5, -.1, 0, .1, .2, .3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`.

```
Clear[x, y, Φ];
x[ν_, μ_] = Cosh[μ] Cos[ν];
y[ν_, μ_] = Sinh[μ] Sin[ν];
Φ[ν_, μ_] = -(1/4) E^(-2 μ) Cos[2 ν] - 
   1/2 μ;
meshs = {-3, -2, -1, -.9, -.8, -.5, -.1, 0, .1, .2, .3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
ParametricPlot[{x[ν, μ], y[ν, μ]}, {ν, 
  0, π}, {μ, -2, 2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> 
  Function[{x, y, ν, μ}, Φ[ν, μ]], 
 Mesh -> {meshs}, 
 MeshShading -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ Rescale[meshs]]
```

[image]

- Similar with the 3D version.

```
x[ν_, μ_] = Cosh[μ] Cos[ν];
y[ν_, μ_] = Sinh[μ] Sin[ν];
Φ[ν_, μ_] = -(1/4) E^(-2 μ) Cos[2 ν] - 
   1/2 μ;
meshs = {-3, -2, -1, -.9, -.8, -.5, -.1, 0, .1, .2, .3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
ParametricPlot3D[{Φ[ν, μ], x[ν, μ], 
  y[ν, μ]}, {ν, 0, π}, {μ, -2, 2}, 
 ViewPoint -> Right, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {meshs}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#1] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, Axes -> {False, True, True}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]
```

[image]