# Probable Bug in HighlightMesh with 2D Convex Hulls created via ConvexHullMesh

Tags: functions, bugs, computational-geometry

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2**

---

One nice way to view the new and exciting `Mesh` objects introduced in **Version 10** is by utilizing the function `HighlightMesh`, so I've been using it heavily. Problem is, when trying to visualize 2D convex hull regions (3D case works fine) created using `ConvexHullMesh`, `HighlightMesh` essentially ignores the `Options` for styling the face of the 2D polygon region. Here is an example:

```
SeedRandom[0];
pts = RandomReal[4, {200, 2}];
chull = ConvexHullMesh[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now let's `Style` it using `HighlightMesh`

```
HighlightMesh[chull, {Style[0, Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]], 
  Style[1, Thin, Green], Style[2, Directive[Yellow]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the `Yellow` `Color` under `Style[2, ..]`, that's for the `Polygon` face. This is obviously ignored for the `Default` color used above. Can anyone reproduce this on **Windows 8.1** and other operating systems and is there an easy workaround for this?

Comment: There are no 2-dimensional mesh elements in `chull`, only lines and points (examine `chull // InputForm`).  I had the same problem [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55352/plot-the-plane-so-different-condition-has-a-different-color/55360#55360). I did not explain the difficulty, but I did come up with a workaround.

Comment: @MichaelE2 So why does `MeshCells[chull, 2]` give an output - a `Polygon`?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm not sure at this point I'm able to give an authoritative answer to any "why" about mesh objects.  It looks like an inconsistency to me.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I saw your answer but you didn't use `HighlightMesh` to `Style` it, which is designed specifically to do this. I think it's an omission. And I agree, the `Mesh` objects weren't fully fleshed out.

Comment: I didn't use it because it didn't work.  Also `MeshCell[..., 2]` does not seem to work on it either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16085/discussion-between-runnykine-and-michael-e2).

Comment: Behavior still present in 10.0.1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Yeah, I don't think they touched any of the `Region` bugs we uncovered. Maybe in 10.0.2 they'll get to them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternative workaround is to convert the `BoundaryMeshRegion` into a `MeshRegion` from the `MeshCoordinates` and `MeshCells`. This lets you use `HighlightMesh` as desired:

```
SeedRandom[0];
pts = RandomReal[4, {200, 2}];
chull = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
styles = MapThread[Style, {{0, 1, 2}, {Red, Green, Yellow}}];

fullmesh[bm_] := MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[bm], MeshCells[bm, All]]

HighlightMesh[chull, styles]
HighlightMesh[fullmesh @ chull, styles]
```

[image]
[image]

Note that this won't work for higher dimensional regions:

```
MeshCells[ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {4, 3}]], 3]
```

> MeshCells::cnorep: There is no simple cell representation for the
>   specified cells of the BoundaryMeshRegion in dimension 3.

Comment: Nice workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a workaround that's easy enough since it makes use of the already created `Mesh` region:

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[
  MeshCoordinates[chull], {Green, MeshCells[chull, 1], Red, 
   PointSize[0.02], MeshCells[chull, 0], Opacity[0.6], Yellow, 
   MeshCells[chull, 2]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]