# How to make a region plot indicating the largest among a set of functions

Tags: plotting

I want to make a `RegionPlot` (or possibly a `ContourPlot`) in $x$-$y$ space that indicates which among a set of functions is the biggest value for a given $(x, y)$.

Suppose I have (in this example) three functions assembled in a list:

```
f[x_, y_] = Sin[x*y]
g[x_, y_] = Cos[x*y/2]
h[x_, y_] = Sin[x*y^2/7 + 2 \[Pi]/E]
(*and possibly more...*)

list[x_, y_] = {f[x,y], g[x,y], h[x,y]}
```

and I want to paint a region *blue* if `f[x]` is largest in that region, *magenta* if `g[x]` is largest and *dark yellow* if `h[x]` is largest.  The end result would be collage of colors corresponding to largest among the functions.

Is there a way using functional coding to do this?  I'm looking for fastest fastest possible computing speed.

Any hints on possibly helpful *Mathematica* functions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to construct the inequalities (see also [Plot the plane so different condition has a different color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55352/plot-the-plane-so-different-condition-has-a-different-color)):

```
fns = {Sin[x*y], Cos[x*y/2], Sin[x*y^2/7 + 2 \[Pi]/E]};
colors = {Blue, Magenta, Darker@Yellow};
rgns = Table[And @@ Thread[fns[[i]] >= Drop[fns, {i}]], {i, Length[fns]}];

Show[MapThread[
  RegionPlot[#1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ##2] &,
   {rgns, Thread[PlotStyle -> colors]}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are some small gaps.  They may be removed in this case with `PlotPoints -> 60`.

---

**Addition**

Even though on further consideration, it seems to me that this question is a duplicate of the one I linked to above, I'll add this, because it's fast and uses a small amount of memory.  Increase `PlotPoints` for smoother contours.

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> meshfns, Mesh -> {{0}}, Axes -> False];
With[{pts = First@Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[p_, __] :> p, Infinity]},
 plot /. GraphicsComplex[p_, g_, opts___] :> GraphicsComplex[p,
    Last@Reap[
      plot /. 
       poly : Polygon[pp_] :> {
         Sow[#, First @ Position[Through[meshfns @@ Mean[pts~Part~#]], _?Positive]] & /@ 
          pp},
      Range@Length@colors,
      {colors[[#1]], Polygon[#2]} &
      ],
    opts]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Isn't this question an almost exact duplicate of the one you linked to?

Comment: @RahulNarain The region functions (from my answer) do not work on this region.  So my initial reaction was that there was a difference.  But kguler's solution would work here, if `Min` were replaced with `Max`. (I didn't consider it until you asked.)