# How to do a region plot with many functions

Tags: plotting

Hello i am trying to compare many function, i want to see witch one as the lowest value depending on 2 variables.

My solution so far is something like this:

I have 7 function: P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7, variable are v and d:

```
RegionPlot[{
    P1 [d, V, A] <= P2[d, V, A] &&
   P1 [d, V, A] <= P3[d, V, A] &&

   P1 [d, V, A] <= P4[d, V, A] &&
   P1 [d, V, A] <= P5[d, V, A] &&

      P1 [d, V, A] <= P6[d, V, A] &&
   P1 [d, V, A] <= P7[d, V, A] ,
  P2[d, V, A] < P1[d, V, A] &&
   P2[d, V, A] <= P3[d, V, A] &&

   P2[d, V, A] <= P4[d, V, A] &&
   P2[d, V, A] <= P5[d, V, A] &&

   P2[d, V, A] <= P6[d, V, A] &&
   P2[d, V, A] <= P7[d, V, A],
  P3[d, V, A] < P1[d, V, A] &&
   P3[d, V, A] <= P2[d, V, A] &&

   P3[d, V, A] <= P4[d, V, A] &&
   P3[d, V, A] <= P5[d, V, A] &&

   P3[d, V, A] <= P6[d, V, A] &&
   P3[d, V, A] <= P7[d, V, A],
  P4[d, V, A] < P1[d, V, A] &&
   P4[d, V, A] <= P2[d, V, A] &&

   P4[d, V, A] <= P3[d, V, A] &&
   P4[d, V, A] <= P5[d, V, A] &&

   P4[d, V, A] <= P6[d, V, A] &&
   P4[d, V, A] <= P7[d, V, A],
  P5[d, V, A] < P1[d, V, A] &&
   P5[d, V, A] <= P2[d, V, A] &&

   P5[d, V, A] <= P3[d, V, A] &&
   P5[d, V, A] <= P4[d, V, A] &&

   P5[d, V, A] <= P6[d, V, A] &&
   P5[d, V, A] <= P7[d, V, A],
  P6[d, V, A] < P1[d, V, A] &&
   P6[d, V, A] <= P2[d, V, A] &&

   P6[d, V, A] <= P3[d, V, A] &&
   P6[d, V, A] <= P4[d, V, A] &&

   P6[d, V, A] <= P5[d, V, A] &&
   P6[d, V, A] <= P7[d, V, A],
  P7[d, V, A] < P1[d, V, A] &&
   P7[d, V, A] <= P2[d, V, A] &&

   P7[d, V, A] <= P3[d, V, A] &&
   P7[d, V, A] <= P4[d, V, A] &&

   P7[d, V, A] <= P5[d, V, A] &&
   P7[d, V, A] < P6[d, V, A]},
 {d, 0, 2}, {V, -0.1, 0.3},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red], Directive[Blue], Directive[Orange], 
   Directive[Yellow], Directive[Purple], Directive[Green], 
   Directive[Black]}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotPoints -> 20]
```

and i might want to compare more thna 7 function... is there a fast way to do it

thanks

Comment: Although no one's posted Michael E2's `Ordering`-based solution at the previous question.

Comment: @RahulNarain  My memory must be bad. It wasn't even that long ago that I answered that Q.  I've added this method to my answer, in case this one is closed.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a different approach to consider.  `Ordering[fns, 1]` returns the index of the function whose value is least for given numeric values for `x` adn `y`.  (Should there be a tie, it will return the first index only).  We can use this in `ContourPlot` to plot the regions.

```
fns = {x + y, 2 x - y, 1 - x^2 - y^2, (x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 - 2, 2 Sin[x y] - 1/2};

ContourPlot[Ordering[fns, 1], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Contours -> 1/2 + Range[Length@fns - 1], MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

With a list of your functions

```
functions = {P1[d, V, A], P2[d, V, A], P3[d, V, A], P4[d, V, A], P5[d, V, A], P6[d, V, A]};
```

you can create a list of all combinations using

```
And @@ # & /@ MapIndexed[Drop, 
               Partition[#[[1]] < #[[2]] & /@ Tuples[functions, 2], Length @ functions]]
```

Comment: I have mixed feelings about compact notation such as `And @@ # & /@` , so powerful on the on hand, but on the other hand so hard to parse for new users.