# How to draw a tropical surface?

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra, inequalities

By definition, a tropical surface in $\mathbb R^3$ is the set of points $(x,y,z)$ where the maximum $f=\max(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n)$ is attained at least twice, here $f_i$ stand for some linear functions of the type $a+ix+jy+kz, a\in \mathbb R,i,j,k\in\mathbb Z$.

The most basic example is a tropical plane, which is given by $f=\max(x,y,z,0)$. It is easy to see that the set of points which we interested in, is $\{(x,y,z)|x=y\geq \max(z,0)$ or $x=z\geq \max(y,0)$ or$  ... x=0\geq \max(y,z)...\}$, so it is a union of six hyperplanes.

One can use an equivalent definition: the tropical surface is the set of points where $f$ is not smooth (or, equivalently, not linear).

Here is the question: given $f_1,f_2,\dots$ of the above form we need to draw the set where $f=\max(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n)$  is not smooth.
In principle, one can elaborate all all the possible inequalities ($f_1=f_2\geq f_i$ for all $i$ etc), but there should be more elegant way to do that.
Could you help me?

**Added: the simplest way, proposed by  belisarius Apr 13 at 16:12,** seems to be

```
fns[u_, v_, w_] := {u, v, w, 0}; k = 20;
RegionPlot3D[First@Differences[Sort[fns[u, v, w]][[1 ;; 2]]] == 0,
             {u, -k, k}, {v, -k, k}, {w, -k, k}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

but it draws only a part of all points (for the function $\min(x,y,z,0)$ attained twice), without the points $(0,a,b),(a,0,b),(a,b,0)$ with $a,b>0$. How could that be?

Comment: Please include in your question the Mathematica code you have developed so far to address your problem.

Comment: somewhat related [Plot the plane so different condition has a different color](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55352/125)?

Comment: to bbgodfrey: I produced the code illustrating the last idea: for each pair of indices $i,j$ we construct the inequalities $f_i=f_j\geq f_k$ for all $k$. The problem is not in this code. I believe that there should be a fast way for a function of type $\max(,,,)$ to find the set where it is not linear, or where the maximum is attained twice.

Comment: to kguler: Yes, thank you, it seems it will work. I try to do like there.

Comment: Perhaps `fns[u_, v_, w_] := {u, v, w, 0};
k = 20;
RegionPlot3D[
 First@Differences[Sort[fns[u, v, w]][[1 ;; 2]]] == 0, {u, -k, 
  k}, {v, -k, k}, {w, -k, k}, PlotPoints -> 50]`

Comment: to belisarius: it is cool, but that doesn't draw the points of the type (0,a,b),(a,0,b),(a,b,0) with a,b>0 while it must draw them....

Comment: Sounds like holidays to me!

Comment: Nikita, please see my updated answer. @belisarius, your method produces a blank plot for me. Can you explain what it's supposed to do? I don't usually see `RegionPlot`s with equalities in them...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple way to enumerate all the conditions:

```
fs = {x, y, z, 0};
conds = Table[{Equal @@ fs1, 
               And @@ Table[First@fs1 >= f, {f, Complement[fs, fs1]}]}, 
              {fs1, Subsets[fs, {2}]}]
(* {{x == y, x >= 0 && x >= z}, {x == z, x >= 0 && x >= y}, 
    {x == 0, x >= y && x >= z}, {y == z, y >= 0 && y >= x}, 
    {y == 0, y >= x && y >= z}, {z == 0, z >= x && z >= y}} *)
```

Each item `{e, i}` in the list is a pair containing an equality and a conjunction of inequalities, which you can use as `ContourPlot3D[e, ..., RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, i]]`. Draw the whole surface by using `Show` to put them all together.

```
Show[Table[
  ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@First@c, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Last@c]], {c, conds}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is fun! $(x^2-y^2,y^2-z^2+1,z^2-x^2-1)$: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MBoL0.png