# Converting a 3D Plot to a Region Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

I have a 3D Plot with 3 separate functions for `z` in terms of `x` and `y`. I would like to convert this to a RegionPlot with the `max` of the three functions plotted for the variables `x` and `y`.

Essentially, this would be the top view of the 3D Plot, as whatever function is visible from the top is the highest and thus the maximum at that point.

However, I also need to add a `Manipulate` to this so it cannot merely be an image of the top view of the 3D Plot.

```
 Manipulate[
 Plot3D[{0.1, 
     Piecewise[{{α - ((2 α - 1)  α)/y + (
         x*α^2)/(2 y ), (1 - α) + α^2/(2 y) >= 
         0.35}}], 
     Piecewise[{{α + (1 - α)^2/(
         2 y), (1 - α) + (((3 α - 
               1) - ((Abs[1 - x]) (1 - α))) (1 - α))/(
          2 y) >= 0.35}}], 
     Piecewise[{{α - ((2 α - 1) α)/((2 - 
            a) 2) + ((3 - 2 a - Abs[x - a] ) α^2)/(
         2 y*(2 - a)^2), (1 - α) + α^2/(2 y (2 - a)) >= 
         0.35}}]} /. {a -> ((1 + z)/2), x -> 1} // 
   Evaluate, {α, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Orange, Blue}], {{y, 2, 
   Gamma}, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

I would like a 2D Plot from this top view

Comment: Please add your function and code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are three example functions,

```
f1 = Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
f2 = .5 Sin[x - y];
f3 = .002 x^2 + .07 y^2;
```

And here is a top-down view of the 3D plot,

```
Plot3D[{f1, f2, f3}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ViewCenter -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

And here is the same view, using `RegionPlot`

```
RegionPlot[{
  f1 > f2 && f1 > f3,
  f2 > f1 && f2 > f3,
  f3 > f1 && f3 > f2},
 {x, -6, 6}, {y, -4, 4},
 BoundaryStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Or, using your example,

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{flist, f1, f2, f3, f4},
   flist = {f1, f2, f3, f4} = 
       Evaluate[{0.1, 
             Piecewise[{{α - ((2 α - 1) α)/

            y + (x*α^2)/(2 y), (1 - α) + α^2/(2 \
y) >= 0.35}}], 

       Piecewise[{{α + (1 - α)^2/(2 y), (1 - α) + 
            (((3 α - 
                   1) - ((Abs[ 
                    1 - x]) (1 - α))) (1 - α))/(2 y) >= \

                     0.35}}], 

       Piecewise[{{α - ((2 α - 1) α)/((2 - 
                               a) 2) + ((3 - 2 a - 
                               Abs[x - a]) α^2)/(2 y*(2 - 

                 a)^2), (1 - α) + α^2/(2 y (2 - a)) >= 
                     0.35}}]} /. {a -> ((1 + z)/2), x -> 1}];
   RegionPlot[{
       f1 == Max@flist,
       f2 == Max@flist,
       f3 == Max@flist,
       f4 == Max@flist
       }, {α, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
     BoundaryStyle -> None
     , PlotPoints -> 50, PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Orange, Blue}]
  ]
  , {{y, 2, Gamma}, 1, 5}]
```

Using the `PlotPoints` option severely slows it down, but makes the plot smoother.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58257/4999) applied to this question:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{fns = {0.1, 
      Piecewise[{{α - ((2 α - 1) α)/y + (x*α^2)/(2 y), (1 - α) + α^2/(2 y) >= 0.35}}], 
      Piecewise[{{α + (1 - α)^2/(2 y),
         (1 - α) + (((3 α - 1) - ((Abs[1 - x]) (1 - α))) (1 - α))/(2 y) >= 0.35}}], 
      Piecewise[{{α - ((2 α - 1) α)/
           ((2 - a) 2) + ((3 - 2 a - Abs[x - a]) α^2)/(2 y*(2 - a)^2),
         (1 - α) + α^2/(2 y (2 - a)) >= 0.35}}]} /. {a -> ((1 + z)/2), x -> 1}}, 
  ContourPlot[Ordering[fns, -1], {α, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   Contours -> 1/2 + Range[Length@fns - 1], 
   ContourShading -> {Black, Green, Orange, Blue}, 
   MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[1, 4]]
  ],
 {{y, 2, Gamma}, 1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]