# Ranking Based Partitioning with Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, mathematical-optimization, color

I have **three** functions f_1, f_2, f_3 defined on =[0,a]×[0,b] and I want to color in blue (resp. red, green) the region of points (x,y)∈ where f_1(x,y)=Max(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y)) (resp. f_2(x,y)=Max(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y)), f_3(x,y)=Max(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y))). How to do that? I know that with only two functions, it is enough to use **RegionPlot** :

RegionPlot[f_1[x,y] < f_2[x,y], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}]

But how to do this with **three** functions **and not only two**? Is there a **simple solution?**

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
f1[a_, b_] := Sin[a] Cos[b]
f2[a_, b_] := Sinc[a] Sin[b]
f3[a_, b_] := Cos[a] Sinc[b]

ContourPlot[
  Ordering[{f1[a, b], f2[a, b], f3[a, b]}, -1], {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 5}
  , PlotPoints -> 100
]
```

[image]

If so your question is a duplicate of [Plot the plane so different condition has a different color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55352/121)

(which I couldn't find before posting)

Comment: Oh Yes! Thank you so much Mr.Wizard!