# Coloring Points in a DensityPlot/ListDensityPlot

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, grid-layouts, plotting

I have a PDE system, whose functions are $a=a(t, x, y)$, $b=b(t,x,y)$, and $c=c(t,x,y)$,

[image]

with Dirichlet null boundary conditions and initial conditions in the form of circle.

[image]

The respective code is,

```
 L = 5;(*length of square*)
pts = 150;
T = 250;(*Time integration*)
Df = 1;
σ = 0.6;
µ = 0.3;
(*system of nonlinear PDE*)
pde = {D[a[t, x, y], t] == 
    Df (D[a[t, x, y], x, x] + D[a[t, x, y], y, y]) + µ (1 - 
        a[t, x, y] - b[t, x, y] - c[t, x, y]) a[t, x, y] - σ c[
       t, x, y] a[t, x, y], 
   D[b[t, x, y], t] == 
    Df (D[b[t, x, y], x, x] + D[b[t, x, y], y, y]) + µ (1 - 
        a[t, x, y] - b[t, x, y] - c[t, x, y]) b[t, x, y] - σ a[
       t, x, y] b[t, x, y], 
   D[c[t, x, y], t] == 
    Df (D[c[t, x, y], x, x] + D[c[t, x, y], y, y]) + µ (1 - 
        a[t, x, y] - b[t, x, y] - c[t, x, y]) c[t, x, y] - σ c[
       t, x, y] b[t, x, y]};
(*Dirichlet boundary condition*)
bc = {a[t, -L, y] == 0, a[t, L, y] == 0, a[t, x, -L] == 0, 
   a[t, x, L] == 0, b[t, -L, y] == 0, b[t, L, y] == 0, 
   b[t, x, -L] == 0, b[t, x, L] == 0, c[t, -L, y] == 0, 
   c[t, L, y] == 0, c[t, x, -L] == 0, c[t, x, L] == 0};
(*initial condition*)
ic = {a[0, x, y] == If[(x)^2 + (y - 2.5)^2 <= (L/4)^2, 1, 0], 
   b[0, x, y] == If[(x + 2.5)^2 + (y + 2.5)^2 <= (L/4)^2, 1, 0], 
   c[0, x, y] == If[(x - 2.5)^2 + (y + 2.5)^2 <= (L/4)^2, 1, 0]};
eqns = Flatten@{pde, bc, ic};
sol = NDSolve[eqns, {a, b, c}, {t, 0, T}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> pts, "MaxPoints" -> pts}}];
```

I would like to plot $6$ frames ($y \times x$) using DensityPlot (or ListDensityPlot) for the times $t=0$, $t=50$, $t=100$, $t=150$, $t=200$, $t=250$. I would like also to represent $a(t, x, y)$ $\rightarrow $ red color, $b(t, x, y)$ $\rightarrow $ blue, and $c(t, x, y)$ $\rightarrow $ green.

At each point $(x, y)$, if $a(t, x, y)$ has the highest value in relation to $b(t, x, y)$ and/or $c(t, x, y)$ to color the respective point with red color. If at some point $(x, y)$, $b(t, x, y)$ has the largest value in relation to $a(t, x, y)$ and $c(t, x, y)$ to color that point with blue. If at any point $(x, y)$, $c(t, x, y)$ has a value greater than $a(t, x, y)$ and/or $b(t, x, y)$, then to color the respective point with green.The figure below shows the expected scheme

[image]

can anybody help me?

Comment: I can see your images and my `sol` does not appear to give those results.  Nevertheless I think you should be able to apply the methods I show in my answer; please try them and report.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard perfect! There is only one thing that is not working well, in regions where a, b and c are 0, it is coloring green, it could be white. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: I provided an approach that I think works for your case, using Plot3D.  I could not think of a clean way to do this using ContourPlot.  Please let me know if this does in fact work for you, and if not I'll try again.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you so much! It's working very well.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the case were a, b, c are all zero, it seems easiest to me to use `Plot3D` for this case, with the addition of [`ClipPlanes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html). I used a small offset (`-0.03`) for the position of the plane to remove some of the noise that occurs if I use `0` in its place.

```
t = 0;

Block[{x, y, val = Through @ sol[[1, All, 2]][t, x, y]},
  Plot3D[val, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}
   , PlotPoints -> 50
   , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}
   , Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
   , Mesh -> False
   , ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}
   , ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, 1, -0.03}}
  ]
]
```

[image]

---

For some reason imgur images are not loading for me at the moment so I cannot see your goal plot.  However I think I get the idea of what you want, and we can apply Michael's method from [Plot the plane so different condition has a different color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55352/121#58257) like this:

```
t = 5;

ContourPlot[
  Ordering[Through @ sol[[1, All, 2]][t, x, y], -1],
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}
  , PlotPoints -> 50
  , ContourShading -> {Red, Green, Blue}
]
```

[image]

Or using [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) as in [my own answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55358/121)

```
Block[{x, y, val = Through @ sol[[1, All, 2]][t, x, y]},
  Plot3D[val, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}
   , PlotPoints -> 50
   , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}
   , Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
   , Mesh -> False
   , ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}
  ]
]
```

[image]