# At how many of these points is f(x,y) (strictly) greater than both g(x,y) and h(x,y)? and

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

[image]

I try too find out the solution but is not work. Please help!

This what I wrote:
[image]

Comment: Tangentially related: [(55352)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55352/121)

Answer (score 1):

First, [define functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

Next, use [Outer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) to get the function values as matrices..

Matrices can be compared elementwise.

Answer (score 1):

Posting code rather than images helps people providing answers.

There are syntax errors in the image of the code. `sin` should be `Sin`.

Here is an approach defining functions (as suggested by @Alan) and using [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html), though [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) and matrices could be used.

The solution to the first question can be plotted to confirm result. I leave the second question to OP. I hope this is instructive:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + y^2 - 30 x y - 2
g[x_, y_] := x Sin[x + y] + 6 y
h[x_, y_] := (x^3 + y^3)/(x^2 + Exp[y/100])
mesh = Tuples[Range[-1, 1, 0.1], 2];
fm = f @@@ mesh;
gm = g @@@ mesh;
hm = h @@@ mesh;
fg = Sign[fm - gm] /. -1 -> 0;
fh = Sign[fm - hm] /. -1 -> 0;
pos = Position[fg fh, 1] ;
ans = Extract[mesh, pos]
Length[ans]/Length[mesh]
Show[Plot3D[{f[x, y], g[x, y], h[x, y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Point[{#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} & @@@ ans]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Consider `ans = Pick[mesh, fg fh, 1];`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you. I must admit I did not spend much time on this but Pick is much nicer way to extract flat list. Appreciate the feedback. :)

Comment: Just for fun: `Pick[mesh, Last@*Ordering@*Through /@ {f, g, h} @@@ mesh, 1]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard love the use of left composition and Ordering. I continue to enjoy the creativity even if I have not been around as much. Thanks for the comments:)

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + y^2 - 30*x*y - 2;
g[x_, y_] := x*Sin[x + y] + 6*y
h[x_, y_] := (x^3 + y^3)/(x^2 + Exp[y/100]);

pointsf = Table[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}] // Flatten;
pointsg = Table[g[x, y], {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}] // Flatten;
pointsh = Table[h[x, y], {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}] // Flatten;

pointsf // MapIndexed[(# > pointsg[[First@#2]] && # > pointsh[[First@#2]]) &] // Counts

(* <|False -> 289, True -> 152|> *)
```